# SQL query to show zero instead of not shown record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables:

**Reception**

```
id  reception_date      tin_lot company_id  client_id   quantity    weight
1   2013-12-03 00:00:00 1       1           1           10          1980.00
2   2013-12-03 00:00:00 2       1           1           1           150.00
3   2013-12-13 00:00:00 3       1           2           10          4500.00
4   2013-12-13 00:00:00 4       2           5           5           2300.00
```

**Payment**

```
id  payment_date        amount  reception_id
1   2013-12-03 00:00:00 500.0   1
2   2013-12-03 00:00:00 1200.0  3
```

The result I want to obtain is the following:

**Expected result**

```
id  reception_date      tin_lot client_id   weight      payment_made
1   2013-12-03 00:00:00 1       1           1980.00     500.0
2   2013-12-03 00:00:00 2       1           150.00      0.0
3   2013-12-13 00:00:00 3       2           4500.00     1200.0
4   2013-12-13 00:00:00 4       5           2300.00     0.0
```

I'm trying this query:

```
select rec.id
rec.reception_date,
rec.tin_lot,
rec.client_id,
rec.weight,
pay.payment_made
from liquidation.reception rec, liquidation.payment pay
where pay.recepcion_id=rec.id
```

But it doesn't list the receptions with no payment.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you need to learn to use `left outer join` and proper join syntax.  Just don't use a comma in a `from` clause any more.

Here is the query you want:

```
select rec.id, rec.reception_date, rec.tin_lot, rec.client_id, rec.weight,
       coalesce(pay.payment_made, 0) as payment_made
from liquidation.reception rec left outer join
     liquidation.payment pay
     on pay.recepcion_id = rec.id;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly [Gordon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff). Thank you very much.

Comment: Certainly a left join seems to solve the original question - but even if the LEFT/RIGHT/INNER/FULL OUTER JOIN syntax made the older form redundant (it doesn't) that would not mean it's deprecated as implied in your answer.

Comment: @symcbean . . . You are welcome to your opinion, but you are in a decided minority if you prefer the older syntax.  The need for this question, in fact, clearly shows the superiority of the explicit use of joins.

Comment: That's very interesting. Thank you for the shared knowledge. But now I have a question, how can I include another table to the `from` block? As you can see there's a 'client_id' column and I would like to display the client name that is stored in a `client` table. How can I do this without using the older syntax?

Answer (score 1):

you need to Left Join the payment table:

```
from liquidation.reception rec
left join  liquidation.payment pay on ( pay.recepcion_id=rec.id)
```